A dashed line from dashrightarrow but without an arrow
Is there a dashed line that looks like $\dashrightarrow$ but without the arrow tip? (The length is the same, just arrow to be removed.) A solid line can be found at below link
A longer dash like the line from rightarrow without an arrow tip
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,marvosym}

\begin{document}

$A\dashrightarrow B$

$A\CuttingLine B$

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! To be able to compare with \dashrightarrow I would need to know which \dashrightarrow. symbols-a4.pdf known several packages with this command. So please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. But maybe you are searching for something like \CuttingLine of package marvosym.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,marvosym}
\begin{document}
$A\dashrightarrow B$
$A\CuttingLine B$
\end{document}

I am new here, and I apologize if thee are some errors. Above is a MWE. If I add the CuttingLine command, I got a letter R. In this example, I just need to remove the arrow tip in the dashed line between A and B.

Here is a rough approximation.

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx}

\newcommand{\mydash}{\mathrel{\scalebox{.5}[1]{$---$}}} 

\begin{document} 

$A\dashrightarrow B$ 

$A\mydash B$

\end{document}

If you want something more precise you can design your own with TikZ:

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb, tikz}

\newcommand{\mydash}{\mathrel{\kern.84pt\tikz[baseline=-.58ex]{
    \draw[dashed, dash pattern=on 2.94pt off 2.04pt, line cap=round](0,0)--(.454,0);
}\kern.84pt}} 

\begin{document} 

$A\dashrightarrow B$ 

$A\mydash B$

\end{document}

